# How to deploy a procedure automatically which is present in a clob column

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, package

I have a table which has a clob column. And in the clob column I have a package which I would like to be compiled without manually intervention.Can anyone tell me if this is possible or not in PLSQL.

Note: The package in the clob column is not already present in the database. This is something new which I want to be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "without manual intervention", but yes you can create an object e.g. package from data stored in a CLOB column. for example:

```
insert into mytable (id, clob_col) values
 (1, 'create or replace package p1 as procedure proc1; end;');

commit;
```

Then

```
declare
   clob_val clob;
begin
  select clob_col into clob_val
    from mytable
   where id = 1;
  execute immediate clob_val;
end;
```

Of course, a package has two parts, the specification and the body.  So you ideally need to store these separately (e.g. 1 row for the spec and another for the body).  If they were within the same CLOB value then you would need to parse the CLOB value and extract them singly before running the `execute immediate`.

Comment: Tony & the others, sorry for jumping into this discussion & going off topic. Do you know what happened to dBforums? Is it *dead*? I can't access it for ... phew, a month or so; I'm being redirected to some other site, but couldn't find any info about it.

Comment: @Littlefoot I hadn't noticed as not tried for a month or two, but I see what you mean. No idea what happened.

Answer (score 2):

If there were several PL/SQL procedures in a table, you'd use a loop. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, col clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values
  2  (1, 'create or replace package pkg_test as '      ||
  3      '   function today return date; '             ||
  4      'end;'
  5  );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values
  2  (2, 'create or replace package body pkg_test as ' ||
  3      '   function today return date is '           ||
  4      '   begin '                                   ||
  5      '     return sysdate; '                       ||
  6      '   end; '                                    ||
  7      ' end;'
  8  );

1 row created.

SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 is
  3      select id, col
  4        from test
  5        order by id;
  6    c1r c1%rowtype;
  7  begin
  8    open c1;
  9    loop
 10      fetch c1 into c1r;
 11      exit when c1%notfound;
 12
 13      execute immediate(c1r.col);
 14    end loop;
 15    close c1;
 16  end;
 17  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select pkg_test.today from dual;

TODAY
----------------
30.01.2018 12:50

SQL>
```

WooHoo! It works!